# Is there any way to configure proxy-authentication for OAuthPrompt Dialog?

Tags: c#, botframework

Hosting an on-prem Chat Bot behind the proxy. Trying to find out a way to customize the HttpClient within OAuthPrompt Dialog so i can configure the proxy setting.

```
AddDialog (new OAuthPrompt (
    nameof (OAuthPrompt),
    new OAuthPromptSettings {
        ConnectionName = _configuration["ConnectionName"],
            Text = "Please login",
            Title = "Login",
            Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
    }));




private async Task<DialogTurnResult> IntroStepAsync (WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync (nameof (OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically for the OAuth piece, but you can run the whole bot through a proxy.

## 1. Create a Proxy Class

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ProxyBot
{
    public class MyProxy : IWebProxy
    {
        public MyProxy()
        {
            //here you can load it from your custom config settings 
            this.ProxyUri = new Uri("<myProxyUrl:Port>");
        }

        public Uri ProxyUri { get; set; }

        public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            return this.ProxyUri;
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            //you can proxy all requests or implement bypass urls based on config settings
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

## 2. Add the proxy class to `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<MyProxy>();
```

You may need to update your Bot.Builder packages; we've made some recent changes for proxy support.